# Automating Executable Jar File

Tags: java, winforms, jar, automation

I have a file formA.jar which have lots of textboxes, listboxes and a submit button. How would I create another java file which could do the following to formA.jar:

- Run formA.jar
- Automatically fill-out formA.jar textboxes, listboxes
- Automatically click the submit button

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the JAR developed by you ? is it acceptable to modify that code to solve this problem ?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't develop the jar file

Comment: Ok. If you were the developer of JAR, you could accept the parameter from main method and use that text to populate the textbox and call a method which is called on click of button..Anyway I dont think it is possible in Java..but nice question so +1

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's sad to know. Do you know some programming language that could do that? Like C# controlling jar file/program?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? I'm also interested in a solution to this problem.